# Need help calling Web Api controller methods to retrieve data

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm new to Web Api (I'm probably missing something very straightforward here) I have a Web Api project with `ProductsController.cs` that has a property of type `List<Product>` and I simply want to call the Api in the browser eg `localhost/api/products/1` or `/api/products/getproduct/1` to retrieve the product response for the specified Id in the url but I cannot get it to retrieve any data. I get a 'not found' error each time. What am I missing to make it find the data and retrieve the response?

I have tried the following:

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id)
{
    var product = products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
    if (product == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    else
    {
        return Ok(product);
    }
}
```

And even the following which still returns not found:

```
public string Get(int id)
{
   return "product test";
}
```

Comment: Above of your method, you need to add like: `[HttpPost]
        [Route("~/api/products/")]` I don't know neither what's the name of those lines, though...

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave thank you for your comment. I think it's called attribute routing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the the routing is configured properly

WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        // Attribute routing.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

From there you have two options of routing to the action.

Convention-based.

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController {

    //...constructor code removed for brevity

    [HttpGet] // Matches GET api/products
    public IHttpActionResult GetAllProducts() {
        return Ok(products);
    }

    [HttpGet] // Matches GET api/products/1
    public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id) {
        var product = products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
        if (product == null) {
            return NotFound();
        } 
        return Ok(product);
    }
}
```

or Attribute routing

```
[RoutePrefix("api/products")]
public class ProductsController : ApiController {

    //...constructor code removed for brevity

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")] // Matches GET api/products
    public IHttpActionResult GetAllProducts() {
        return Ok(products);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:int}")] // Matches GET api/products/1
    public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id) {
        var product = products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
        if (product == null) {
            return NotFound();
        } 
        return Ok(product);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer I will try this later. In terms of best practices is it better to use the attribute routing approach or convention based? What would happen if you used both together?

Comment: @Theomax  It all depends on preference of developer. each option has its pros and cons. App can utilize/mix both options across multiple controllers. However a single controller either uses convention-based or attribute routing.

Comment: Adding [HttpGet] to GetProducts(int id) worked for the URL /api/products/1 although I don't understand why because it doesn't reference that method name apart from the fact it is a HttpGet method that takes an int parameter. I tried doing the same for a method called GetAllProducts() which should return the whole collection of products, but obviously it cannot be invoked with /api/products/GetAllProducts - would I need to map it in routeconfig?

Comment: @Theomax because you have multiple GETs in the controller you have to specify the `HttpGet` on the 2 actions `GetAllProducts` and `GetProducts`. `GetAllProducts` would map to ` /api/products` because `{id}` is optional.  `GetProducts(int id)` would then map to ` /api/products/1`